# Error using tkz-euclide and \tkzIntersectionCC[R]

Tags: errors, fp, tkz-euclide

The `tkz-euclide` and  `\tkzIntersectionCC[R]` produces:

`FP error #1: "Logarithm of negative value!"`

The code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,14.5){centerClip}
    \tkzDrawCircle[R,color=red](centerClip,4.5 cm)
    \tkzClipCircle[R](centerClip,4.5 cm)
    \foreach \y in {1, ..., 8}  {
        \tkzDefPoint(0,\y){O\y}
        \tkzDrawCircle[R](O\y, 10 cm)
    }
    \tkzDefPoint(-14.5, 14.5){newOrigin}
    \begin{scope}[shift = (newOrigin)]
        \foreach \x in {1, ..., 14}  {
            \tkzDefPoint(0.7*\x, 0){Q\x}
            \tkzDrawCircle[R](Q\x, 9 cm)
        }
    \end{scope}
    \tkzInterCC[R](O5, 10 cm)(Q7, 9 cm)
    \tkzGetPoints{I}{I'}
    \tkzDrawPoints[color = red, size = 12, fill = red](I, I')
    \foreach \o in {1, ..., 8}
        \foreach \q in {1, ... 14}{%
            \tkzInterCC[R](O\o, 10 cm)(Q\q, 9 cm)}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is solved by asking only for the relevant intersections, e.g.,

```
\tkzGetPoints{}{I'} % note empty {}
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,pifont,latexsym}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview} 
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}

\begin{document} 
\begin{preview}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1]
\tkzDefPoint(-0.2,14.6){centerClip}
\tkzDrawCircle[R,color=red](centerClip,4.5 cm)
%\tkzClipCircle[R](centerClip,4.5 cm) % uncomment to clip
\foreach \y in {1, ..., 9}  {
    \tkzDefPoint(0,\y - 2){O\y}
    \tkzDrawCircle[R, style = dashed, thin, color = lightgray](O\y, 11.5 cm)
}
\tkzDefPoint(-14.5, 14.5){newOrigin}
\begin{scope}[shift = (newOrigin)]
    \foreach \x in {1, ..., 12}  {
        \tkzDefPoint(0.8*\x, 0){Q\x}
        \tkzDrawCircle[R, style = dashed, thin, color = lightgray](Q\x, 8.7 cm)
    }
\end{scope}
\foreach \o in {1, ..., 9}
    \foreach \q in {2, ..., 12}{%
        \tkzInterCC[R](O\o, 11.5 cm)(Q\q, 8.7 cm)
        \tkzGetPoints{}{I'}
        \tkzDrawPoints[color = red, size = 12, fill = red](I')
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```